# How to fix 'Address not mapped' in MPI_Send?

Tags: c++, mpi

I made a cluster application using MPI. It calculates some problem using master-slave design. Everything works just fine but when the slave process has to send its result back to the master process, it fails right in the MPI_Send with the 'Address not mapped'.

This is the code that handles the communication between the slave and the master.

```cpp
void main_slave( int width, int height ) {
    int transferSize = 6 + width * height;
    int responseSize = 1 + width * height;
    int* buffer = new int[transferSize];
    int* response = new int[responseSize];
    MPI_Status status;
    while ( true ) {
        MPI_Recv( buffer, transferSize, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
        if ( status.MPI_TAG == TAG_DONE ) break;
        State state = deserialize_task( width, height, buffer );
        task_solve( state );
        response[0] = maximum;
        serialize_board( best, &response[1] );
        MPI_Send( response, responseSize, MPI_INT, 0, TAG_DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    delete[] buffer;
    delete[] response;
}
```

This is the error output I get when it fails. In there you can see that it fails right in the MPI_Send for some reason.

```
[star:27344] *** Process received signal ***
[star:27344] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[star:27344] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[star:27344] Failing at address: 0x584f4f4fa0
[star:27344] [ 0] /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf5d0)[0x7f85705155d0]
[star:27344] [ 1] /usr/lib64/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_send+0x68)[0x7f8565987d08]
[star:27344] [ 2] /usr/lib64/libmpi.so.40(PMPI_Send+0xf2)[0x7f85711e0792]
[star:27344] [ 3] run.exe[0x402977]
[star:27344] [ 4] run.exe[0x4035f0]
[star:27344] [ 5] /usr/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f857015b3d5]
[star:27344] [ 6] run.exe[0x4016c9]
[star:27344] *** End of error message ***
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `MPI_Send( &response, ...` ?

Comment: The root cause is very likely in some code that is not shown here. please edit your question with a [MCVE].